# Trying to update the DOM

Tags: dom, vue.js

I obviously fell into the Vue.js caveat, I suppose. Anyway:
I am rendering a v-if list of items (notes) and I want to reverse it when the checkbox is checked.

I get the data from store (Axios get) and assign it immediatelly to a different property (appNotes) so I can manipulate it later. I can't get the notes to update on the first render. They do when I check the box. Here's the relevant code:

```
  <div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" id="appNotes" class="form-check-input" @click="handleClick"
  v-model="check">
  <label for="appNotes" class="form-check-label" >Older Notes First</label>
  <!-- {{check? this.appNotes=[...this.notes].reverse():this.appNotes=this.notes}} -->
  <!-- This surprisingly reverses the notes and produces s warnig about inifinite loop -->
</div>
<section class="row text-center text-lg-left " v-if="notes.length">
  <NoteThumb 
  v-for="note in appNotes" 
  :key="note.id" 
  :note="note">
    <h4>{{ note.title }}</h4>
    <p>{{ note.date }}</p>
    <p>{{ note.id }}</p>
  </NoteThumb>
</section>


  data(){
    return {
      appNotes: {},
      check:false
  },
  handleClick(){
    this.check? this.appNotes=[...this.notes].reverse():this.appNotes=this.notes
  },
  passNotes(){
    this.$set(this.appNotes, this.notes, null)
    this.appNotes=null
    this.$forceUpdate()
  },
  async created (){
  await this.$store.dispatch('notes/getNotes')
  await this.passNotes()
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/2jqr60xmjj
it's not a working link, but you can see the full code at the 'Home' component

Comment: Please provide the part of the template which renders the list of items. As far I understand the problem is that the list of items is not rendered until you click on the checkbox - am I right ? Can you provide a full codepen ?

Comment: @BeniaminH Yes that's right, I need to check the box, and it updates

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version (these 4 lines took me all day lol):

```
in computed:
    appNotes(){
        let reverse=this.notes.slice().reverse()
        return this.check? reverse:this.notes
    }
```

I removed everything else. It turns out it was simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for you to take out the @click="handleClick" and create a watch property for check. So after you load the asynchronous request you can set the check to false and then it will render your list of notes.

```
<template>
<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" id="appNotes" class="form-check-input" v-model="check">
  <label for="appNotes" class="form-check-label" >Older Notes First</label>
  <!-- {{check? this.appNotes=[...this.notes].reverse():this.appNotes=this.notes}} -->
  <!-- This surprisingly reverses the notes and produces s warnig about inifinite loop -->
</div>
<section class="row text-center text-lg-left " v-if="notes.length">
  <NoteThumb 
  v-for="note in appNotes" 
  :key="note.id" 
  :note="note">
    <h4>{{ note.title }}</h4>
    <p>{{ note.date }}</p>
    <p>{{ note.id }}</p>
  </NoteThumb>
</section>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                appNotes: {},
                check:false
            };
        },
        methods:
        {
        passNotes(){
            this.$set(this.appNotes, this.notes, null)
            this.appNotes=null
            this.$forceUpdate()
            //here you can just set check to false and it will update the appNotes
            this.check = false
         },
        async created (){
            await this.$store.dispatch('notes/getNotes')
            await this.passNotes()
        }
        },
        watch: {
            check: function () {
                this.check? this.appNotes=[...this.notes].reverse():this.appNotes=this.notes
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting tips, thanks. After finding the solution, I (again) tried like you suggested this:
  watch: {
    check:()=>{
      console.log(this.notes)
    }
  } 
Somehow, 'notes' is undefined, which doesn't make sense.